# How do I re-initialize a python pyqt5 gui

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a simple program consisting out of two QWidgets. One is an input window and the other is the output window. The input window has a QlineEdit of which the value is passed to the output window QlineEdit once I hit Apply using a signal and slot. What my current program looks like:

[image]

Up to this point everything works fine. What I want to achieve is that depending on the number I give in the input a similar number of 'Entry options' (new QlineEdits) should appear in the output window. What I want to achieve:

[image]

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve. Below you will find my working code as is in picture 1. And I am just getting into programming, so at this stage small examples of code help me more than, often dry, manuals.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sys


class Input(QWidget):

    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.input_label = QLabel('Entries:', self)
        self.input_cell = QLineEdit()
        self.apply_button = QPushButton('Apply')
        self.apply_button.setEnabled(False)

        self.hboxLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.hboxLayout.addWidget(self.input_label)
        self.hboxLayout.addWidget(self.input_cell)
        self.hboxLayout.addWidget(self.apply_button)

        self.setLayout(self.hboxLayout)

        self.input_cell.textChanged.connect(self.apply_change)

        self.setWindowTitle("Input window")
        self.show()

    def apply_change(self, value):
        self.apply_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.send_this = value
        self.apply_button.clicked.connect(self.send_value)

    def send_value(self, value):
        if value is False:
            self.dataChanged.emit(self.send_this)
            self.apply_button.setEnabled(False)


class Output(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Output window')

        self.content()

        self.show()

    def content(self):
        layout = QGridLayout()
        output_label = QLabel('Nr. of entries:', self)
        self.output_cell = QLineEdit()

        entry_label_1 = QLabel('Entry1:', self)
        entry_cell_1 = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(entry_label_1, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(entry_cell_1, 2, 2)
        entry_label_2 = QLabel('Entry2:', self)
        entry_cell_2 = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(entry_label_2, 4, 0)
        layout.addWidget(entry_cell_2, 4, 2)

        layout.addWidget(output_label, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.output_cell, 0, 2)

        layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def make_connection(self, input_object):
        input_object.dataChanged.connect(self.get_input_value)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def get_input_value(self, val):
        self.output_cell.setText(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    inp = Input()
    out = Output()
    # Making the connection
    out.make_connection(inp)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@saelyth answer is interesting but uses memory improperly since it is creating layouts every time the number is changed, my solution does not create more layouts but reuses them.

To do this we must make some changes to create a more stable code:

1. Set a `QIntValidator` to `QLineEdit` so that the user is forced to place only numbers:

---

```
self.input_cell.setValidator(QIntValidator(0, 1000, self))
```

2. Change the QGridLayout to QFormLayout since it is optimized to have a label next to another widget.

---

```
layout = QFormLayout(self)
```

3. We must add items with `addRow()` and remove items with `removeRow()`:

---

```
@pyqtSlot(str)
def get_input_value(self, val):

    self.output_cell.setText(val)
    val_int = int(val)

    if val_int > (self.layout().rowCount() - 1):
        [self.hboxLayout.addRow('Entry '+str(i), QLineEdit(self)) for i in range(self.layout().rowCount(), val_int+1)]

    elif val_int < (self.layout().rowCount() - 1):
        for i in range(self.layout().rowCount(), val_int, -1):
            child = self.hboxLayout.removeRow(i)
```

Complete Code:

```
class Input(QWidget):

    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.input_label = QLabel('Entries:', self)
        self.input_cell = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_cell.setValidator(QIntValidator(0, 1000, self))
        self.apply_button = QPushButton('Apply')
        self.apply_button.setEnabled(False)

        self.hboxLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.hboxLayout.addWidget(self.input_label)
        self.hboxLayout.addWidget(self.input_cell)
        self.hboxLayout.addWidget(self.apply_button)

        self.setLayout(self.hboxLayout)

        self.input_cell.textChanged.connect(self.apply_change)
        self.apply_button.clicked.connect(self.send_value)

        self.setWindowTitle("Input window")
        self.show()

    def apply_change(self, value):
        self.apply_button.setEnabled(True)

    def send_value(self, value):
        if value is False:
            self.dataChanged.emit(self.input_cell.text())
            self.apply_button.setEnabled(False)


class Output(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Output window')
        self.content()
        self.show()

    def content(self):
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.output_cell = QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addRow('Nr. of entries:', self.output_cell)
        layout.setSpacing(10)

    def make_connection(self, input_object):
        input_object.dataChanged.connect(self.get_input_value)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def get_input_value(self, val):

        self.output_cell.setText(val)
        val_int = int(val)

        if val_int > (self.layout().rowCount() - 1):
            [self.layout().addRow('Entry '+str(i), QLineEdit(self)) for i in range(self.layout().rowCount(), val_int+1)]

        elif val_int < (self.layout().rowCount() - 1):
            for i in range(self.layout().rowCount(), val_int, -1):
                child = self.layout().removeRow(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The good new is that half of your issue is easy to fix. Replace your code for this and execute it to see the result.

```
def content(self):
    layout = QGridLayout()
    output_label = QLabel('Nr. of entries:', self)
    self.output_cell = QLineEdit()

    for x in range(3):
        entry_label_1 = QLabel('Entry'+str(x)+':', self)
        entry_cell_1 = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(entry_label_1, x+1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(entry_cell_1, x+1, 2)

    layout.addWidget(output_label, 0, 0)
    layout.addWidget(self.output_cell, 0, 2)
    layout.setSpacing(10)
    self.setLayout(layout)
```

In my example I use range(3) as example for a loop, to tell the program to create 3 textboxes. If you change that for range(10)... well, take a guess.

Now the tricky part is that you just need to capture the input data and replace `range(3)` with `int(self.output_cell.text())` and it'll be done. However, there is a lot of ways to accomplish that. You choose to use signals while I mostly use globals on my programs so I don't completely know how it would work for you. I'll update this answer when I find an easy way to do it.

Comment: I am seeing that you are creating layouts at any moment, that is not good since it creates and uses memory in an irresponsible way. If you improve that problem you could give upvote.

Comment: I also realized that issue. Working on it.

Comment: I surrender. I really hate gridlayouts and while still learning pyqt5 myself, I don't think I'll find an efficient way to do it. Would had been easier for me with just geometry. At least I hope the OP understand that a loop might help him on that issue (sometimes).

Comment: My solution does not generate this problem :P

Comment: Oh, so much to learn yet. But you also changed the gridlayout! I tried to keep it and... oh boy haha. I'll take this as a lesson.

Comment: The answers should help the questioner in improving his code, not just the immediate problem but the problem. It is better to propose a simple solution than a fancy solution and that can generate problems. :P